# SQL Server : create record fails when trigger is enabled

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, triggers

I have a very old application that I must support. I'm pushing (hard) to replace it but you know what management can be like. The front end is in Access 97 and it has linked tables in SQL Server 2008 R2 for the data storage.

It has been working smoothly for many years and I usually refuse to modify it.

I have been requested to send an automatic email whenever a new record is created in a particular table. I have been sending emails from SQL Server Agent jobs in the past so I thought it wouldn't be too hard to send an email from a trigger when the record is created, thus avoiding the need to make changes to the Access97 front end.

I have created my trigger with lots of logging to file built in so I can tell if it falls over part way through, which it doesn't.

The error message I'm getting on the client is

> "ODBC--Insert on a linked table 'dbo_Quote' failed."

This is the table being inserted and the one with the trigger.

I'll post the trigger code here if someone really wants to see it but I don't think the problem is there. It is a little long with all my debugging code in there.

To prove it works I commented out all the lines like this

```
set @MASuburb = (select Rtrim(MASuburb) from inserted)
```

and just set the variables manually after declaring them the code works when run directly.

After removing the test changes I then ran my application with the trigger disabled and used SQL Server Profiler to capture the query that was executed and the insert succeeded.

I then deleted the record created, enabled my trigger again.

Pasted the captured query in Management Studio and it ran end to end and sent the email. The problem is only when the query comes directly from Access.

I can't figure out why SQL Server sends a failure message back to Access if the trigger is enabled.

I have been looking for some better error messages but nothing seems to be logged anywhere.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can locate the problem?

(Yeah yeah I know get rid of Access)

Thanks in advance
David

**UPDATE**
Here is the trigger code.  I removed much of the debug logging.

```
USE [Quote]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[NewManagementQuotationEmail] 
   ON  [Quote].[dbo].[Quote]  
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Declare Fields Used
    Declare @DateEntered        datetime
    set @DateEntered = ''
    Declare @ContactName        nvarchar(50)
    set @ContactName = ''
    Declare @PreparedFor        nvarchar(50)
    set @PreparedFor = ''
    Declare @MailAddress1       nvarchar(50)
    set @MailAddress1 = ''
    Declare @MailAddress2       nvarchar(50)
    set @MailAddress2 = ''
    Declare @MASuburb           nvarchar(50)
    set @MASuburb = ''
    Declare @MAState            nvarchar(3)
    set @MAState = ''
    Declare @MAPcode            nvarchar(10)
    set @MAPcode = ''
    Declare @SPNumber           nvarchar(10)
    set @SPNumber = ''
    Declare @SPAddress1         nvarchar(50)
    set @SPAddress1 = ''
    Declare @SPAddress2         nvarchar(50)
    set @SPAddress2 = ''
    Declare @SPSuburb           nvarchar(50)
    set @SPSuburb = ''
    Declare @SPState            nvarchar(3)
    set @SPState = ''
    Declare @SPPcode            nvarchar(10)
    set @SPPcode = ''
    Declare @NumberOfUnits      int
    set @NumberOfUnits = ''
    Declare @PricePerUnit       money
    set @PricePerUnit = ''
    Declare @TotalAnnualFee     money
    set @TotalAnnualFee = ''
    Declare @Stationary         money
    set @Stationary = ''
    Declare @ContactPhoneW      nvarchar(15)
    set @ContactPhoneW = ''
    Declare @ContactPhoneH      nvarchar(15)
    set @ContactPhoneH = ''
    Declare @ContactPhoneM      nvarchar(15)
    set @ContactPhoneM = ''
    Declare @Fax                nvarchar(15)
    set @Fax = ''
    Declare @Email              nvarchar(50)
    set @Email = ''
    Declare @WhyChooseUs        nvarchar(50)
    set @WhyChooseUs = ''
    Declare @CurrentlyManagedBy nvarchar(50)
    set @CurrentlyManagedBy = ''
    Declare @DateSent           datetime
    set @DateSent = ''
    Declare @CallBackDate       datetime
    set @CallBackDate =''
    Declare @EnteredBy          nvarchar(15)
    set @EnteredBy = ''

    -- Setup Debug Logging 
    Declare @Debug int
    -- 0=OFF >=1 ON --
    Set @Debug = 2

    if @Debug > 0
    Begin
        DECLARE @cmd varchar(255)
        DECLARE @var varchar(255)
        DECLARE @logfile char(50)
        SET @logfile =  '>> C:\temp\NewManagementQuotationEmailLog.txt' 
        SET @var = cast(GetDate()as varchar)+ ': ' + '======= Trigger NewManagementQuotation Trigger Executed ======= (Quote Database, Quote Table)'
        SET @cmd = 'echo ' + @var + @logfile
        EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
    End
    Return
    --=======================================================================================
    -- Declare the variable to send the email

    Declare @VAR_EmailAddress varchar(100)
    Declare @VAR_Subject varchar(100)
    Declare @VAR_Body  varchar(4000)
    --Declare @VAR_FileName varchar(50)
    Declare @NewLine varchar(10)
    Set @NewLine = CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)

    set @VAR_EmailAddress = '<My Email Goes here>'
    set @DateEntered = (select DateEntered from inserted)
    set @ContactName = (select Rtrim(ContactName) from inserted)
    set @PreparedFor = (select Rtrim(PreparedFor) from inserted)
    set @MailAddress1 = (select Rtrim(MailAddress1) from inserted)
    set @MailAddress2 = (select Rtrim(MailAddress2) from inserted)
    set @MASuburb = (select Rtrim(MASuburb) from inserted)
    set @MAState = (select Rtrim(MAState) from inserted)
    set @MAPcode = (select Rtrim(MAPcode) from inserted)
    set @SPNumber = (select Rtrim(SPNumber) from inserted)
    set @SPAddress1 = (select Rtrim(SPAddress1) from inserted)
    set @SPAddress2 = (select Rtrim(SPAddress2) from inserted)
    set @SPSuburb = (select Rtrim(SPSuburb) from inserted)
    set @SPState = (select Rtrim(SPState) from inserted)
    set @SPPcode = (select Rtrim(SPPcode) from inserted)
    set @NumberOfUnits = (select NumberOfUnits from inserted)
    set @PricePerUnit = (select PricePerUnit from inserted)
    set @TotalAnnualFee = (select TotalAnnualFee from inserted)
    set @Stationary = (select Stationary from inserted)
    set @ContactPhoneW = (select Rtrim(ContactPhoneW) from inserted)
    set @ContactPhoneH = (select Rtrim(ContactPhoneH) from inserted)
    set @ContactPhoneM = (select Rtrim(ContactPhoneM) from inserted)
    set @Fax = (select Rtrim(Fax) from inserted)
    set @Email = (select Rtrim(Email) from inserted)
    set @WhyChooseUs = (select Rtrim(WhyChooseUs) from inserted)
    set @CurrentlyManagedBy = (select Rtrim(CurrentlyManagedBy) from inserted)
    set @DateSent = (select DateSent from inserted)
    set @CallBackDate = (select CallBackDate from inserted)
    set @EnteredBy = (select Rtrim(EnteredBy) from inserted)

    --================================================================================================  
    if @Debug > 0
    Begin
            SET @var = cast(GetDate()as varchar)+ ' 2) Generate Email to Trello started'
            SET @cmd = 'echo ' + @var + @logfile
            EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
    End

    if @Debug > 0
    Begin
            SET @var = cast(GetDate()as varchar)+ ' 3.0) Query Text String Begin'
            SET @cmd = 'echo ' + @var + @logfile
            EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
    End

    Set @VAR_Subject = @SPNumber 
    set @VAR_Body = 'Date Entered= ' + cast(@DateEntered as varchar(12)) + CHAR(13)+ CHAR(10) +
                    'Contact Name= ' + @ContactName + CHAR(13)+ CHAR(10)  +
                    'Prepared for= ' + @PreparedFor + CHAR(13)+ CHAR(10)  +
                    'Mail Address 1= ' + @MailAddress1 + CHAR(13)+ CHAR(10)  +
                    'Mail Address 2= ' + @MailAddress2 + CHAR(13)+ CHAR(10)  +
                    'Mail Address Suburb= ' + @MASuburb + CHAR(13)+ CHAR(10)  +
                    'SP Address 1= ' + @SPAddress1 + CHAR(13)+ CHAR(10)  +
                    'SP Address 2= ' + @SPAddress2 + CHAR(13)+ CHAR(10)  +
                    'SP State= ' + @SPState + CHAR(13)+ CHAR(10)  +     
                    'SP Suburb='     + @SPSuburb + CHAR(13)+ CHAR(10)  +
                    'SP Post Code= ' + @SPPcode + CHAR(13)+ CHAR(10)  +
                    'Number of Units= ' + cast(@NumberOfUnits as varchar(5)) + CHAR(13)+ CHAR(10)  +
                    'Price Per Unit= ' + cast(@PricePerUnit as varchar(10)) + CHAR(13)+ CHAR(10)  +
                    'Total Annual Fee= ' + cast(@TotalAnnualFee as varchar(10)) + CHAR(13)+ CHAR(10)  +
                    'Stationary= ' + cast(@Stationary as varchar(10))  + CHAR(13)+ CHAR(10)  +
                    'Contact Phone W= ' + @ContactPhoneW + CHAR(13)+ CHAR(10)  +
                    'Contact Phone H= ' + @ContactPhoneH + CHAR(13)+ CHAR(10)  +
                    'Contact Phone M= ' + @ContactPhoneM + CHAR(13)+ CHAR(10)  +
                    'Fax= ' + @Fax + CHAR(13)+ CHAR(10)  +
                    'Email= ' + @Email + CHAR(13)+ CHAR(10)  +
                    'Why Choose Us= ' + @WhyChooseUs + CHAR(13)+ CHAR(10)  +
                    'Currently Managed by= ' + @CurrentlyManagedBy + CHAR(13)+ CHAR(10)  +
                    'Date Sent= ' + cast(@DateSent as varchar(12)) + CHAR(13)+ CHAR(10)  +
                    'Call Back Date= ' + cast(@CallBackDate as varchar(12)) + CHAR(13)+ CHAR(10)  +
                    'Entered By= ' + @EnteredBy

    if @Debug > 0
    Begin
            SET @var = cast(GetDate()as varchar)+ ' 3.9) Query Text String Complete'
            SET @cmd = 'echo ' + @var + @logfile
            EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
    End


    EXEC  msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
        @recipients = @VAR_EmailAddress,
        @subject = @VAR_Subject, 
        @profile_name = 'SQL Email Profile',
        @body= @VAR_Body

    if @Debug > 0
    Begin
            SET @var = cast(GetDate()as varchar)+ ' 4) Generate Email to Trello complete'
            SET @cmd = 'echo ' + @var + @logfile
            EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
    End

    --================================================================================================

    if @Debug > 0
    Begin
            SET @var = cast(GetDate()as varchar)+ '======= Trigger NewManagementQuotation Trigger Complete ======='
            SET @cmd = 'echo ' + @var + @logfile
            EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
    End
End
```

**Update 2**
No change in the error message after adding keyword "Return"
My Trigger log only contains one line as expected

```
Apr  7 2017  5:15PM: ======= Trigger NewManagementQuotation Trigger Executed ======= (Quote Database, Quote Table)
```

Just to make sure it is clear.  I can capture the SQL generated by Access with the trigger disabled and run it again directly in Microsoft Management Studio with the trigger enabled and it works.  So it seems to me like Access is misinterpreting the return code from SQL Server some how or SQL Server is returning the wrong code when the trigger is enabled. That is what I need to figure out.

**Update 3** 
This is the SQL generated by Access that I captured in SQL Profiler

```
    exec sp_executesql  N'INSERT INTO  "dbo"."Quote"  
(
    "DateEntered",
    "ContactName",
    "PreparedFor",
    "MailAddress1",
    "MASuburb",
    "MAState",
    "MAPcode",
    "SPNumber",
    "SPAddress1",
    "SPSuburb",
    "SPState",
    "SPPcode",
    "NumberOfUnits",
    "PricePerUnit",
    "Stationary",
    "ContactPhoneW",
    "ContactPhoneH",
    "ContactPhoneM",
    "Email",
    "WhyChooseUs",
    "CurrentlyManagedBy",
    "DateSent",
    "CallBackDate",
    "StatusId",
    "EnteredBy"
) 
VALUES (@P1,@P2,@P3,@P4,@P5,@P6,@P7,@P8,@P9,@P10,@P11,@P12,@P13,@P14,@P15,@P16,@P17,@P18,@P19,@P20,@P21,@P22,@P23,@P24,@P25)',N'
    @P1 datetime,
    @P2 char(50),
    @P3 char(50),
    @P4 char(50),
    @P5 char(50),
    @P6 char(3),
    @P7 char(10),
    @P8 char(10),
    @P9 char(50),
    @P10 char(50),
    @P11 char(3),
    @P12 char(10),
    @P13 int,
    @P14 decimal(19,4),
    @P15 decimal(19,4),
    @P16 char(15),
    @P17 char(15),
    @P18 char(15),
    @P19 char(50),
    @P20 char(50),
    @P21 char(50),
    @P22 datetime,
    @P23 datetime,
    @P24 int,
    @P25 char(15)',

'2017-04-07 00:00:00',
'Farley Bainsworth                                 ',
'Bob Johnson                                       ',
'15 Boburgal Ave                                   ',
'Kirrawee                                          ',
'NSW','2232      ',
'101010    ',
'100 Armdale Rd                                  ',
'The Land                                            ',
'NSW','2460      ',
100,
50.0000,
500.0000,
'02 66493300    ',
'02 66493693    ',
'0418256742     ',
'bobpollard@gmail.com                             ',
'Why Not                                           ',
'Bob the Builder                                   ',
'2017-04-07 00:00:00',
'2017-08-07 00:00:00',1,
'bpollard       '
go
```

Comment: "ODBC--Insert on a linked table 'dbo_Quote' failed." - Do you get additional error info when you *run query in ssms* + *trigger enabled*?

Comment: No, it succeeds in SSMS.  Successfully creates the email and inserts the record with no errors.

Comment: Not related (probably) to your current problem, but your trigger is badly broken. `inserted` can contain 0, 1, or **multiple** rows. All of those selects into scalar variables will break badly when the latter situation occurs.

Comment: I understand what you are saying however the application will only ever insert one row. (not sure how you can insert zero rows)  What would be a more appropriate way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer but more of a conclusion.

I decided to give up on Access and talked my boss into redeveloping the application in Visual Studio.

This created a whole lot of new problems but at least we will be using software in the current century before it is half over :)

Thanks for your comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Does the after insert (assuming) trigger on the table dbo_quote contains some insertion on another table which has a trigger? If so, you might check the insertion code for which the variables are getting used.

Comment: Yes it is an After Insert trigger.  The database is quite simple with only 4 tables.  There are no other triggers at all.  At first I thought it might be some kind of constraint problem but there aren't any constraints.
There is one Foreign Key that holds a StatusID that points to a record in a Status Table.

Comment: My doubt is what is exactly happening in the after insert trigger of the quote table. I mean are you doing any insert operations?

Comment: I'll add the trigger query to the question.  It is long but so be it :)

Comment: It'll be helpful if we could get a glimpse of that since we can be pretty sure (It is) that the trigger is causing the error.

Comment: I forgot to add there is no insertion in the trigger.  It collects the details and calls a stored procedure to generate the email.  I wonder what Access is expecting as a return code and if my trigger is mucking that up.

Comment: Just try the below. insert the values into quote table within a transaction (begin and rollback) and just add a return keyword in the trigger below the very first if loop (if debug>0....end return) and check whether that error throws up.

Comment: I have added the "Return" keyword as suggested.  Not sure about adding a transaction as the SQL is generated within Access.  I see what I can figure out.  It is about knock off time Friday here so it may be Monday before I get back to this.  Thanks for your ideas so far.

Comment: Transaction is just a suggestion however you can debug the trigger (by code blocks) by just returning. You have to manually try inserting values in the quote table (In the sql query window) to find out the root cause.